Wolfram Mathematica does not work at all
I have been using mma for years. But after using quit kernal or trying to set default values, mma suddenly stops working. It can not plot sin[x] , evaluate 5+3...
Version: 11.2.0.0
Why?

It's because of the bad weather ... :) No, but seriously, how are we supposed to figure this out? What does it mean "it does not work at all"? Is there any output? An error message? Can you at least post a screenshot, please? :)

This happened to me too quite some time ago so I do not remember precisely what I did to make it to work again but if I remember correctly I had to reconfigure my kernels. Look in Preferences for any options that have something with kernels - like enable local kernels or something similar.

In Evaluation - Default kernel and Evaluation - Notebook's kernel set to Local.

@azerbajdzan  Thanks a lot. It works now.

Try using upper-case Plot[], not plot.

And Sin[x], not sin[x].
